# Why does Amazon SNS spams my elastic beanstalk server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sns

I set up a server on elastic beanstalk, and SNS keeps spamming my server with requests like this:

[23/Sep/2020:12:43:16 +0000] "POST /pubsubmessage HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "-" "Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent"

Do you know what it is, whether I should stop those calls, and how to make them stop?

Comment: Are you running EB worker environment, rather then web environment?

Comment: No I have a web environment